# R ヒストグラム　x軸が名義変数の場合の作図方法を知りたいです。

Tags: r

Rを使って、ヒストグラムを描きたいです。
対象とする変数は、数値の大小に意味がある順序変数ではなく、「名義変数」に分類される業種コード(ex.製造業：01,金融：19,食品:38など)です。

最終的に業種コードごとに度数が表示される図にしたいのですが、現状としてx軸が順序変数としてみなされているため、業種コードのなかでとんでいる(もともと存在しない)番号が数値として残ってしまう状態です。

名義変数のヒストグラムを描く際の、オプションの指定の仕方がわからないため、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

ヒストグラムで描きたい理由がよくわかりませんが、普通の棒グラフではだめなのですか？

```
df <- data.frame(code=c("01", "01", "01", "19", "38", "38"))
qplot(df$code, geom="bar", xlab = "業種コード")
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

[業種コード表(日本標準産業分類)](https://www.pref.mie.lg.jp/common/content/000151581.pdf) から適当に業種を拾ってきてテスト用のデータを作成します。

```r
df <- data.frame(
  "業種" = c(
    "銀行業", "飲食料品小売業", "電気業", "不動産取引業",
    "情報サービス業", "鉄道業", "水道業", "食料品製造業"
  ),
  "業種コード" = c(
    "62", "58", "33", "68", "39", "42", "36", "09"
  )
)

# df["業種コード"] からサンプリング
data <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), size=200, replace=T), "業種コード"]

print(length(data))
# [1] 200

print(data[1:20])
#  [1] "33" "39" "36" "33" "39" "36" "36" "68" "36" "58" "68" "09" "33" "09" "58"
# [16] "58" "39" "62" "58" "33"
```

`factor()` でデータを categorize します。

```r
data <- factor(data, df[,"業種コード"])

plot(data, ylim=c(0, 35), xaxt="n")
text((1:(length(levels(data))))*1.2, par("usr")[3]-0.8,
     labels=df[,"業種"], srt=45, pos=2, xpd=T)
```

[image: histogram]